# Linked list (or map) in Cassandra

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to form a relation between the tables like,

```
parent <-> child <-> child
```

so that I can traverse between the tables to identify the dependencies. It is like the RDBMS referential constraint concept. Is there a way in Cassandra can we mention it, I use Spark SCALA framework which connects to Cassandra.

Thanks,
Ash

Comment: In cassandra there is no referential constraint concept.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. I just want to see if we can use any collections in Cassandra and then handle it in the code.